# Certain parts not loading on ajax requested page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I build this website: http://newslist.ca/

Recently, I changed it so when you chose something different from the drop down menu, the page updated immediately with the new feed. But I noticed that everything that should load based off of that new content doesn't load. Mainly: the sharing buttons, and the number of comments on each article?

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

```
$('.ajax').change(function() {
  var url = "/?cat=" + $("select option:selected")[0].label + "&loc=" + $("select option:selected")[1].label + "&sort=" + $("select option:selected")[2].label;
  console.log(url);

  $.get(url, function (data) {
    $('body').empty();
    $('body').append(data);
  })
});
```

Comment: How about showing us the code you're using.

Comment: I have no idea what isn't working for you. However, I can tell you that you really shouldn't be using ajax this way. ajax is not meant to act as a substitute for reloading the page, it is meant to load small bits of data, and then insert them into the page in the correct places. I think you should rethink how you're doing this.

Comment: Woah. You've solved it, I think. I started off planning on doing it a totally different way, then ended up working to this. Needed a clearer plan from the start. I can just redirect when they change options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The social media icons do not load when you refresh the page content entirely as they are inserted via JavaScript that is waiting for the document body to finish loading and fire an event. My thought is that your comment count method is using a similar method. Xymostech's comment above regarding using Ajax to load small bits of data into the page rather than the entire page contents is correct; you'll most likely want to load the comment counts as data with each item and leave the share tools in place (ie don't reload them) should you decide to revisit the Ajax method.